# Laravel DB get sum of column of left joined table (sum of thumbs up/down against a post)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a reviews site, and users can thumbs up or thumbs down a review. The reviews table existed because I am using a Laravel boilerplate that I found. I've added the thumbs table using migrate and created a model and controller.

These are the two tables in question.

```
reviews
+----+-----------------+------------+-----------+---------+
| id | review_constant | title      | publish   | etc...  |
+----+-----------------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 1  | 1               | Test       | published | blah    |
| 2  | 2               | Test2      | old       | blah    |
| 3  | 2               | Test2 Edit | published | blah    |
+----+-------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+

review_thumbs
+----+---------+-----------------+-------+
| id | user_id | review_constant | thumb |
+----+---------+-----------------+-------+
| 1  |  12     |   2             |  1    |
| 2  |  10     |   2             | -1    |
| 3  |  8      |   2             |  1    |
| 4  |  17     |   2             |  1    |
+----+---------+-----------------+-------+
```

`review_constant` is the original `reviews.id` which is passed to any edits for a single review. We're only interested in rows where `publish = 'published'`.

I can get each published review no problem.

```
Reviews::where( 'publish', 'published' )
```

But I also want the SUM of thumbs that match that review's review_constant, which I can do with SQL

```
SELECT reviews.id, reviews.review_title, rt.review_constant, rt.thumbs
FROM reviews 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT review_constant, SUM(thumb) AS thumbs FROM review_thumbs 
) AS rt ON (rt.review_constant = reviews.review_constant)
where reviews.publish = 'published'
```

I'm struggling to do this in Laravel. I found some instructions telling me I need to add relationships like this

```
class ReviewThumbs extends Model
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Reviews::class, 'review_constant', 'review_constant');
    }
    ...

}

class Review extends Model
{

    public function reviewThumbs(){
        return $this->hasMany(ReviewThumbs::class, 'review_constant', 'review_constant');
    }
    ...
}
```

and then I can do this `Reviews::where( 'publish', 'published' )->with('review_thumbs')`, and that I should then be able to use it in a blade template. I don't know the correct syntax, and everything I do try throws an error. I've tried sum(), count(), using getReviewThumbsAttribute and I'm lost.

```
@if ($review->thumbs->sum() > 0 ) 
    +{{ $review->thumbs->sum() }}
@else
    {{ $review->thumbs->sum() }}
@endif
```

What should be in place of `$review->thumbs->sum()` and if I need to, what methods do I need to add to the PHP classes?

Answer (score 0):

Each `review` has one to many relationship with `review_thumbs` and the `review_constant` column represents `id` of the `review` table. So, your `Review` model should look like,

```php
class Review extends Model {

    public function reviewThumbs(){
        return $this->hasMany(ReviewThumbs::class, 'id', 'post_id');
    }

    public function reviewThumbs(){
        return $this->hasMany(ReviewThumbs::class, 'review_constant', 'id');
    }

    public function thumbsUp(){
        return $this->hasMany(ReviewThumbs::class, 'review_constant', 'id')->where('thumb', '=', 1);
    }

    public function thumbsDown(){
        return $this->hasMany(ReviewThumbs::class, 'review_constant', 'id')->where('thumb', '=', -1);
    }

}
```

Now, for any `review` instance, you can simply count occurrences or sum `thumb` column.

```php
$sum = $review->reviewThumbs()->sum('thumbs');
$thumbUps = $review->thumbsUp()->count();
$thumbDowns = $review->thumbsDown()->count();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `review_constant` doesn't match `id` of review table; it matches `reviews.review_constant`. With that fixed sum() only counts the +ve values. If I adjust the -1's to positive values it adds them up. But when they're less than zero they are ignored. `return $this->hasMany(ReviewThumbs::class, 'review_constant', 'review_constant')->where('thumb', '<', 0);` returns zero even though there are several rows with -1.

Comment: So, when the column is tinyint or decimal it doesn't recognise -1 as -ve but it does recognise -2 as -ve. When the column is varchar it works as expected.